# MutableLiveData value get cleared when try to filter data from its value too frequently

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Scenario:

- I'm a getting list of data from the repository
- Updating the list to a MutableLiveData called `searchedDoctorsListMLD` and to observe the data by exposing another variable called `searchedDoctorListLD`
- Based on the value of the `searchedDoctorListLD` UI is updating (RecyclerView)

Now I have to filter out some item from the `searchedDoctorListLD` based on the user input & update the UI (RecyclerView)

**Approach 1:**

```
    val tempResult = mutableListOf<DoctorInfoDataModel>()
    searchedDoctorListLD.value?.forEach {
        if (it.name.toLowerCase()
                .contains(
                    text.toString()
                        .toLowerCase(),
                    true
                )
        ) {
            tempResult.add(it)
        }
    }
    updateDoctorsList(tempResult)
```

- First time when I search something working fine
- When I clear the input text, UI is updated based on the `searchedDoctorListLD` value

```
    searchedDoctorListLD.value?.let {
        updateDoctorsList(it)
    }
```

- So when I try to filter some item from the list again `searchedDoctorListLD` get cleared (`searchedDoctorsListMLD` also)

**Approach 2:**

I have tried to use a HashMap (by converting the value list (ArrayList) to HashMap) and filter out the data from the HashMap and store the data into the `tempResult` and update the UI

```
    val tempResult =
        mutableListOf<DoctorInfoDataModel>()
    val tempData: HashMap<Int, DoctorInfoDataModel> =
        HashMap()
    searchedDoctorListLD.value?.let {
        tempData.putAll(
            it.toMutableList().toHashMap()
        )
    }
    repeat(tempData.count()) { position ->
        tempData[position]?.let {
            if (it.name.toLowerCase()
                    .contains(
                        text.toString()
                            .toLowerCase(),
                        true
                    )
            ) {
                tempResult.add(it)
            }
        }
    }
    updateDoctorsList(tempResult)
```

- So when I try to filter some item from the list again `searchedDoctorListLD` get cleared (`searchedDoctorsListMLD` also)

Comment: we need more info. How you clear the input? Where is the search function? Is it in the ViewModel or in an Activity/Fragment? All that code is in an Activity? What is in the viewModel? Show more code please

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wj7v7q - I have text field to take input from the EditText. I'm observing the edit text, when input field has any text executing the filter operation & show the filtered data to the recycerlview adapter, else show the list from the live data I have.